# Generating token for Fabric Rest api using client secret

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, fabric, fabric-rest-api

I am working as a POC where I have to connect to Fabric Rest API from c# and I want to create Items. I am able to create items as per the instructions provided on [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/fabric/articles/get-started/fabric-api-quickstart](https://stackoverflow.com).
The challenge I am facing is with token creation. As per the instructions provided on this page, I am getting a login page and after successful authentication, the token is generated.
I am going to use the token creation call inside api but I don't have a provision to authenticate. I need some guidance on how to generate the token using client secret if possible. I am currently using the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
#region parameters section 
string ClientId = "clientID";
string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations";
string RedirectURI = "http://localhost";
#endregion

#region Acquire a token for Fabric APIs 
// In this sample we acquire a token for Fabric service with the scopes  
// Workspace.ReadWrite.All and Item.ReadWrite.All 
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/Workspace.ReadWrite.All https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/Item.ReadWrite.All" };

PublicClientApplicationBuilder PublicClientAppBuilder =
        PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
        .WithAuthority(Authority)
        .WithRedirectUri(RedirectURI);

IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApplication = PublicClientAppBuilder.Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
#endregion
```

I have created a new app registration in Azure active directory and added api permission for Power Bi and azure storage. I also provided the admin consent to the newly added permission. I created a client secret and tried to create a token in postman. The token is created but when using this token, its gives me a bad request. When using the token generated from the c# code, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I registered one Entra ID application and created one **client secret** in it:

[image]

You need to add above service principal to Fabric workspaces giving at least **Contributor** role like this:

[image]

Before generating tokens, make sure to allow access to **service principals** to use Fabric APIs by enabling below option in Admin Portal:

[image]

Now, you can generate access token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope: https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to list workspaces by calling Fabric API, I got the **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/workspaces/
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the same **response** in c# by generating token with client credentials flow, you can make use of below sample code:

```cs
#region
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

string ClientId = "appId";
string ClientSecret = "secret"; 
string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId";
#endregion

#region 
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/.default" };

ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder confidentialClientAppBuilder =
    ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(Authority);

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = confidentialClientAppBuilder.Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
Console.WriteLine();
#endregion


// Create client 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
string baseUrl = "https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

// Call list workspaces API 
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("workspaces");
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
```

**Response:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

When I tried to get the item from workspace where service principal **does not** have at least `Contributor` access, I too got same error:

```
GET https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/items/{itemId}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to grant at least `Contributor` access to the service principal under the **workspace** in which you are getting error:

[image]

When I ran the call after granting access, I'm able to fetch the item successfully by invoking this API:

```
GET https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/items/{itemId}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> But for some other operations like **creating items** in workspace, etc... service principal authentication (client credentials flow) is not **supported**.

When I tried to create item under workspace with service principal token, I got **error** saying *"The operation is not supported for the principal type"* like this:

```json
POST https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/items/
{
    "displayName": "Item 1",
    "type": "Lakehouse" 
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Microsoft Fabric REST APIs | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/fabric/articles/using-fabric-apis#considerations-and-limitation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Followed the same steps as mentioned and when I used this token to list workspaces by calling Fabric API, I also got the response successfully. The problem happens when we invoke any other fabric rest api call like Items - Get Item  (https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/workspaces/{workspaceID}/items/{itemID}), then we will start getting "errorCode": "Unauthorized" and "message": "User is not authorized"

Comment: When I tried to get the item from workspace where service principal does not have at least `Contributor` access, I too got [**same error**](https://i.imgur.com/Csf6evz.png). To resolve the error, make sure to grant at least   [`Contributor`](https://i.imgur.com/2dk2eut.png) access to the service principal under the workspace in which you are getting error. When I ran the call after granting access, I'm able to fetch item invoking `GET https://api.fabric.microsoft.com/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/items/{itemId}` like this:  https://i.imgur.com/pnsYdaX.png

Comment: But for some other operations like **creating items** in workspace, etc... service principal authentication (client credentials flow) is not supported and throws error saying _"The operation is not supported for the principal type"_ like this https://i.imgur.com/RlMeABx.png. To confirm that, you can check this MS Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/fabric/articles/using-fabric-apis#considerations-and-limitation

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yes, I am also getting the same error while creating items in workspace using the token and getting same error message as part of my automation flow. What you suggest the best way for generating token inside api which support the create Item api call based on the current limitation?

Comment: As service principal authentication is not supported to create items in workspace, the only way is to switch to delegated flows by granting Delegated permissions that involves user interaction in acquiring token.

Comment: If your user does not have MFA configured, you can make use of username password **Delegated** flow that acquires token without asking user to sign in. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/desktop-mobile/username-password-authentication But this flow is not recommended as it might disclose user's password.